# Is it possible to receive and save a PDF file in response to a cURL post request in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

php send pdf file in curl response

My curl request :

`request.php`

```
$post = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<request>   
    <stmt_no>123456</stmt_no>
    <from_date>01/05/2023</from_date>
    <to_date>18/05/2023</to_date>   
</request>';
```

```
$target_url = "http://example.com/stmt/Api.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Content-Type: text/xml');

$result=curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

now at **Api.php**, i am receiving these data stmt_no, from_date, to_date and depending on this input i am generating pdf file say xyz.pdf

and i am responding below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
<stmt_no>123456</stmt_no>
<pdfContent>file_get_contents('xyz.pdf')</pdfcontent>
```

now at **request.php** when i am trying to parse response xml with
`$x1=simplexml_load_string($result);`

i am getting below error

`Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in...`

My goal is to send pdf in response and save the same file

Comment: Does this answer your question ? (or provide a good hint ? )  [Making PHP curl request to Download PDF using API url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270278/making-php-curl-request-to-download-pdf-using-api-url)

Comment: Check the XML being returned. Make sure to remove any no printable characters.

Comment: @JasonK , of course there will be  "no printable" character as i am using file_get_contents('xyz.pdf')

Comment: Usually to include binary data in an XML file (or similar) you'd [base64 encode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19893/231316) it

Comment: <pdfContent>base64_encode(file_get_contents('xyz.pdf'))</pdfcontent> did the trick